# Uploading WordPress through the Filezilla FTP program

Tags: wordpress, web, filezilla

I want to put my WordPress blog on my own server. I transferred WordPress and all the files in the public_html folder to my server using FileZilla. When I go to my website I get the following error message: "Error establishing a database connection." I also edited the "wp-config.php" file and updated all the values pertaining to my MySQL database.

Comment: what is your problem ,what u want to do

Answer (score 0):

your half way there, after that go to phpmyadmin, in the wp_options table search for 2 fields: 
siteurl and home and update the link of your homepage accordingly, also update your htaccess file (for friendly urls rewrite) and you are good to go:)

Answer (score 0):

Steps for migrating WordPress from one server to another:

1. copy all your files to the new server using FileZilla (you did
   this)
2. export your MySQL database from old server
3. create new MySQL database at new server
4. import the tables of your database at the new server
5. edit your wp-config.php file to match your MySQL database settings:

   ```
   /* MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host */
   /* The name of the database for WordPress */
   define('DB_NAME', 'prefix_name');
   /* MySQL database username */
   define('DB_USER', 'prefix_user');
   /* MySQL database password */
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
   ```
6. That should be it!

I believe the error message comes from the MySQL database not getting exported and then re-created at the new server with the same username and password.